# How to make this production more 'modular'

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following expression group where everything is thrown into the same `expr` rule:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'

    // BoolExressions -- cannot move these out or else get Left-Recursion
    | expr ('=' | '!=') expr
    | expr 'AND' expr
    | expr 'OR' expr

    | ATOM
    ;

ATOM: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

It works, but I would like to extract the `boolExpression` stuff so that I can use that separately, as some other rules I have must use a boolean expression rather than any expression. However, as soon as I do that I get a left-recursion error.

What would be a good way to break this up, so that I can separate the BooleanExpression stuff? Ideally, I would like it to "look like this":

```
grammar MyGrammar;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'
    | boolExpr
    | ATOM
    ;

boolExpr
    : expr ('=' | '!=') expr
    | expr 'AND' expr
    | expr 'OR' expr
    ;

ATOM: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

// error(119): The following sets of rules are 
// mutually left-recursive [expr, boolExpr]
```

Comment: Antlr in itself does not have a way to augment a rule. The LHS symbol can only be defined once and there is no way of currying rules, and no auto unfold refactoring. You'll have to do it outside of antlr and generate antlr.

Comment: An alternative is to use a chain of rules to implement expressions, e.g., [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/c36708cb47259d2bd75d8d60b8eb8f4119386ac6/csharp/CSharpParser.g4#L92). But that representation slows the parse, and expands the parse tree.

Comment: @kaby76 I see -- why does that slow down the parse though? And if it slows down the parse why did you do that in your above grammar, or is it only a trivial difference?

Comment: Chained rules have more bookkeeping overhead. In the recursive descent parser for the grammar, each rule in the chain requires a decision of the various alternatives, e.g., `'(' expr ')'` or `boolExpr` or `ATOM`. AdaptivePredict() reads ahead in the token stream to make that decision, then the parse continues with that alt. As one recurses to `boolExpr`, a new context is created, and again, AdaptivePredict() is called to make the decision of what to parse (for boolExpr, there are three). Also, the parse trees are much larger.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn’t quite get you a single `boolExpr`, but you should consider labeled alternatives:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'

    // BoolExressions -- cannot move these out or else get Left-Recursion
    | expr ('=' | '!=') expr   # compareExpr
    | expr 'AND' expr          # andExpr
    | expr 'OR' expr           # orExpr

    | ATOM
    ;

ATOM: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

This creates separate *Context classes for each alternative which significantly reduces the complexity of contexts your listeners and visitors will deal with (there will be more of them, though, obviously).  Symbols are also scoped to each alternative so you can do something like:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'

    // BoolExressions -- cannot move these out or else get Left-Recursion
    | lhs=expr ('=' | '!=') rhs=expr   # compareExpr
    | lhs=expr 'AND' rhs=expr          # andExpr
    | lhs=expr 'OR' rhs=expr           # orExpr

    | ATOM
    ;

ATOM: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```